# Отделение букв друг от друга

Tags: python, split

```
text = 'asdefg'
```

нужно сделать так, что бы  в итоге, в результате кода оказалось:

```
text1 =['a', 's', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Answer (score 4):

Для этого есть функция `list()`:

```
text1 = list(text)
```

Comment: Скорее не функция, а просто результат работы конструктора класса list с переданным в него строкой.

Comment: @mydiamondsdancing, ну, имхо, это уже спор о терминах. Есть разные определения функции, и под многие из них конструктор класса вполне подходит. Лично мне применительно к питону импонирует подход, когда функцией называют всё, что является callable.

Comment: @Александр Однако не совсем так. В питоне функция является отдельный объектом, а по поводу callable - так спец.метод __call__ можно определить любом пользовательском классе.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ)