# Можно ли считать функцией любой callable объект?

Tags: python, функции, терминология

В комментариях к ответу на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936688/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0/936690) была поднята интересная тема.

Началась дискуссия с того, можно ли считать list() функцией. Или конструктор класса - это абсолютно отдельная сущность, которая не является функцией?

Далее вопрос встал более обще - можно ли считать функцией любой callable объект, или нет?

Понятно, что есть "настоящие" функции, для которых `type` показывает `<type 'function'>`, а есть остальные объекты, для которых он такого не показывает. Однако, он и для методов показывает вовсе не `<type 'function'>`, а очень даже `<type 'instancemethod'>`. Так что же теперь - методы за функции не считать?

Я был уверен, что в питоне корректно называть функцией любой вызываемый объект. Но гугление мне не выдало каких-то авторитетных источников по данному вопросу, только частные мнения.

Может кто-нибудь отослать меня к авторитетному источнику, который освещает эту тему, или привести какой-нибудь веский аргумент по данному вопросу?

Comment: На 3ем питоне не пишу, но читал, что там instancemethod упразднили. И есть только type <function>. Но по большому счету это одно и тоже. Instancemethod = function by instance

Comment: @Александр, сейчас проверил - выдаёт <function> для метода взятого у класса, и <method> для метода взятого у экземпляра класса. Но вопрос, всё-таки, немножко не про это. Про type просто к слову пришлось.

Comment: @Александр Python 3.7.2 выдал мне `<class 'method'>`, однако

Comment: (слишком много Александров!)

Comment: @andreymal, имя-то распространённое ))

Comment: На мой взгляд, внутреннее определение языка сути не меняет. instancemethod та же функция, но определенная внутри класса. Различия в названии типа служат, в основном, для конкретики. Но это по прежнему фрагмент кода, который можно вызвать из другого фрагмента кода. Может принимать или не принимать аргументы, возвращать или не возвращать значение

Comment: @Александр, любопытно. Сейчас проверил конструктор списка print list.__init__. Он вообще выдаёт, что это это никакой не метод, а slot wrapper для конструктора списка. Аналогично для кастомного типа - bound method. Все-таки встроенные типы - случай уникальный. Я недавно задавался противоположным вопросом, насколько функция - объект и чем она отличается от класса? Прочитал про метаклассы. Попытался превратить функцию в класс назначением последнего. Оказалось, что у функций и классов разные области памяти для хранения. Такое вот приключение.